# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' while using standard vector functions

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I'm working on an assignment which asks us to model an 'elimination voting' procedure for a reality game. For that we use one class (`Vote`) for recording the name of the player to be eliminated and another (`Voting`) which doesn't get instanced anywhere, because its members are static (we need them to be). The votes are stored on a vector inside the Voting class.

The problem is that even when I use the `push_back` function to store the votes in the vector, after running the program for a few times I get an `std::length_error` with `what(): basic_string::_M_create`. After I close it and rerun, the first time I get an error like the one on the title (`std::bad_alloc`).

Any ideas? I'm suspecting that it has to do with the vector not deallocating memory correctly, but I'm not sure.

My code (**Voting.h**):

```
#ifndef VOTING_H_INCLUDED
#define VOTING_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "Vote.h" //ignore this one
#include "Team.h" //this one too

class Voting
{
    public:
        static vector <Vote> votes; //votes cast during voting procedure
        static map <string, int> results; //voting results (key: name, value: number of votes)
        static void votingProcess(Team &team); //the whole voting procedure
};

#endif // VOTING_H_INCLUDED
```

**Voting.cpp**:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Vote.h"
#include "Voting.h"

using namespace std;

vector <Vote> Voting::votes(1);  //initialize the vector for the votes

void voteCast(Team &team);

void Voting::votingProcess(Team &team)
{
    voteCast(team);
}


void voteCast(Team &team)
{
    int playerNumber = team.getNumberOfPlayers(); //number of players right now still in the team
    int votingPlayer = 0; //index of the currently voting player
    int votedPlayerIndex = -1; //index of the player to be voted for elimination
    int reasonIndex = -1; //index of the selected reason for voting
    Vote draft;  //temporary empty vote

    srand(time(NULL)); // initialize the RNG
    Voting::votes.clear(); //clear the vector of any past votes

    string reasons[4] = {"Den ta pame kala metaxi mas", "Einai ikanoteros/i apo emena kai ton/ti theoro apeili", "Den exei na prosferei kati stin omada", "Prospathei sinexeia na sampotarei tis prospatheies mas"};
    //some reasons for elimination (i've tried smaller strings and even chars and it didn't work, so don't bother)

    do
    {
        if (team.getPlayers()[votingPlayer].getAge() != 0 && team.getPlayers()[votingPlayer].getVotes() > 0)
        //if the player with index votingPlayer has not been eliminated and has still votes to cast
        {
            do
            {
                votedPlayerIndex = rand() % 11; //select a random player for elimination
                reasonIndex = rand() % 5; //select a random reason for it
            }
            while ((team.getPlayers()[votedPlayerIndex].getAge() == 0) || (votedPlayerIndex == votingPlayer) || (team.getPlayers()[votedPlayerIndex].getImmunity() == true));
            // selection continues if the selected player has already been eliminated,
            //if the selected player is the same as the voting player or if the selected player has immunity from elimination

            team.getPlayers()[votingPlayer].setVotes(team.getPlayers()[votingPlayer].getVotes() - 1); //reduce the player's available votes by 1

            draft.setVotedPlayer(team.getPlayers()[votedPlayerIndex].getName()); //write the name of the player to be voted in an empty Vote object
            draft.setReason(reasons[reasonIndex]); //and the reason too

            Voting::votes.push_back(draft);  //push the Vote obj. in the vector
        }
        else
        {
            votingPlayer++; //ignore and get to the next player
        }
    }
    while (votingPlayer < playerNumber);  //vote casting continues until every player has casted a vote
}
```

**Vote.h**:

```
#ifndef VOTE_H_INCLUDED
#define VOTE_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vote
{
    string voted; //name of the player to be eliminated
    string reason; //reason for elimination

    public:
        Vote() { voted = ""; reason = ""; } //constructor without parameters

        Vote(string player, string reason) { voted = player; this -> reason = reason;} //constructor with parameters (this one is used)

        ~Vote() { cout << "Vote object destroyed" << endl; }; //destructor

        string getVotedPlayer() { return voted; } //getters

        string getReason() { return reason; }

        void setVotedPlayer(string player) { voted = player; }  //setters

        void setReason(string reason) { this -> reason = reason; }

        void status() { cout << "Voted player: " << voted << endl << "Reason: " << reason << endl;} //status function
};

#endif // VOTE_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Can you show `Vote` as this will need to be copied/moved etc, any issues with it will cause `std::vector` to have problems.

Comment: Why is everything in your class static? Suppose you have more than one game that needs voting on. Also, call srand() _once_, at the very start of your program.

Comment: @NeilButterworth The exercise asks us to make everything static. Every time, there's only one game running. Edited the code to run srand() once, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you have an array with 4 elements (so only indices 0..3 are valid) and you are allowing yourself to index it with the 5 possible values (0..4), where 4 is not a valid index.

Here is the definition of the array:

string reasons[4] = {"Den ta pame kala metaxi mas", "Einai ikanoteros/i apo emena kai ton/ti theoro apeili", "Den exei na prosferei kati stin omada", "Prospathei sinexeia na sampotarei tis prospatheies mas"};

Here is the selection of the index:

reasonIndex = rand() % 5;

Here is the use of that index:

draft.setReason(reasons[reasonIndex]);

That is why you are seeing an error from basic_string::_M_create because you are copying from a value that you have no idea is actually a string.

In the line that sets reasonIndex just change the 5 to a 4.

Comment: Actually, I solved it by myself some days ago, but thanks anyway :)